# Doxygen doesn't distinguish between `union myname` and `struct myname`

Tags: c, doxygen

I've written a small matrix library as part of a larger project I am working on. It was important to have zero-cost transpositions, so I used/abused unions. The code itself works fine (provided below), but when it came to document with Doxygen, it combines all of the documentation for both `struct matrix_r` *and* `union matrix_r` into a single item. That is, there are only generated pages for `struct matrix_r` and `struct matrix_c`, but those two pages describe matrix_r and matrix_c as unions, with concatenated @brief text and concatenated attributes (from both the struct and union declarations).

I am very, very new to Doxygen, but I have been unable so far to figure out how to get it to treat these as separate documentation items. Any ideas?

```
#include <stddef.h>

/// @brief internal stuct for row-major matrices
struct matrix_r {
    int *data; ///< raw pointer backing matrix
    size_t m;  ///< the number of rows
    size_t n;  ///< the number of cols
};

/// @brief internal struct for col-major matrices
struct matrix_c {
    int *data; ///< raw pointer backing matrix
    size_t n;  ///< the number of cols
    size_t m;  ///< the number of rows
};

/// @brief user-facing typedef for row-major matrices
typedef union {
    struct matrix_r id;   ///< identity view of matrix
    struct matrix_c tr;   ///< transposed view of matrix
    int*            flat; ///< flattened view of matrix
} matrix_r;

/// @brief user-facing typedef for row-major matrices
typedef union {
    struct matrix_c id;   ///< identity view of matrix
    struct matrix_r tr;   ///< transposed view of matrix
    int*            flat; ///< flattened view of matrix
} matrix_c;
```

Comment: Though Doxygen may be wrong (and I don't know Doxygen), you are making obfuscated C, having a `struct matrix_r` and a type `matrix_r`. I strongly discourage this.

Comment: After sleeping on it, I will concede the point -- my original intent was that `struct matrix_r` was to never be used directly by users, thus the obscuring of its name to discourage that. I have now, however, renamed the structs to `matrix_r_repr` which still suggests via the `repr` that it's not for external consumption and also eliminates my Doxygen problem as well.

Comment: I just gave about the same comment to another question here :-) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487387/heap-corruption-debug-assertion-failed-in-dbgheap-c-line-1322-expression-crt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural commands start with a backslash `(\)`, or `(@)` followed by a command name and one or more parameters. For instance, if you want to document the class Test , you could have put the following documentation block somewhere in the input that is read by doxygen:

```
/*! \class Test
    \brief A test class.

    A more detailed class description.
*/
```

Straight from the [manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html), here are some other commands:

> Here the special command \class is used to indicate that the comment
>   block contains documentation for the class Test. Other structural
>   commands are:
>
> \struct to document a C-struct.
>
> \union to document a union.
>
> \enum to document an enumeration type.
>
> \fn to document a function.
>
> \var to document a variable or typedef or enum value.
>
> \def to document a #define.
>
> \typedef to document a type definition.
>
> \file to document a file.
>
> \namespace to document a namespace.
>
> \package to document a Java package.
>
> \interface to document an IDL interface.

---

**Edit:** 
I believe this is the way Doxygen is designed to work.  See the 
documentation here: 
http://www.doxygen.nl/autolink.html
in the section "typedefs".  It says:

> Typedefs that involve classes, structs and unions, like
>
> typedef struct StructName TypeName
>
> create an alias for StructName, so links will be generated to 
>   StructName, when either StructName itself or TypeName is  encountered.

Doxygen considers the *union* tag name to be "the real thing", 
not the *typedef* (which is considered like an alias of "the real 
thing"). I'd recommend this:

```
/*!@brief The documentation of the union Name*/ 
typedef union Name 
{ 
    //..... 
}Name;
```

Comment: Even explicitly marking them with \struct or \union, Doxygen combines the documentation entries incorrectly.

Comment: But I don't see them used in your program above. Why so ?
Have you tried commenting them separately, and not struct and union under one `/*   */`

Comment: Have you tried? `/*! \struct test
    \brief short description for struct test
*/

/*! \union test
    \brief short description for union test
*/`
This does not work.

Comment: Check my edit, the problem is the typedef you're using.