# Heap corruption - debug assertion failed. in dbgheap.c line 1322 expression _crtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

At runtime I get debug assertion failed.

```
in dbgheap.c line 1322 expression _crtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

If I run in a debugger I get a breakpoint triggered in line shown below.

How can I fix this allocation/de-allocation error?

I have 2 functions in a header file:

```
struct union_find_t;

struct union_find_t* union_find_init(int n);

void union_find_free(struct union_find_t* uf);
```

and in the .c file the implementation for these 2 functions is:

```
typedef struct union_find_t { 
    int* parent;
    int* rank;
    int components;
} *union_find_t;


struct union_find_t* union_find_init(int n) {

    struct union_find_t* uf = malloc(sizeof(union_find_t));
    uf->parent = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    uf->rank = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    uf->components = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         uf->parent[i] = i;
         uf->rank[i] = 0;
    }
    return uf;
}

void union_find_free(struct union_find_t* uf) {
     free(uf->parent);
     free(uf->rank);
     free(uf);  //*** breakpoint triggered here
}
```

Comment: can you try to run the programm without `free(uf->parent);
     free(uf->rank);` and check if the error come again ..

Comment: `union_find_t;` is a typedef for a pointer, so `malloc(sizeof(union_find_t));` just allocates space for a pointer, and not for the struct. Looks like you should remove the `*` from the typedef.

Comment: @BoPersson - actually your solution is  probably better.  Although typedef struct union_find_t { 
    int* parent;
    int* rank;
    int components;
} union_find_t; looks a little odd

Comment: It's a matter of taste. And if you write `struct union_find_t` everywhere anyway, you don't even need the typedef. The usual reason is to save oneself from having to type `struct` before the name.

Comment: Remove the `*` from the typedef and everything is ok, however, from a structural point of view, you are mixing the `struct` namespace with the `typedef` namespace and the things with same name in both do not have to refer to the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
typedef struct union_find_t
```

is a typedef for:

```
*union_find_t;
```

So when you do this:

```
malloc(sizeof(union_find_t));
```

you just allocate space for *a pointer* to that struct, not for a struct as you need to!

Try with:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct union_find_t));
```

instead.